# React hook form with Material UI checkbox not updating isDirty on first action

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

Using react hook form with MUI controlled checkbox does not set form isDirty property on first interaction. Form is implemented using formContext and fieldArray. After second action on next checkbox it works fine.

Here is my codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/new-mountain-5c4yvj?file=/src/App.tsx

Formstate should be set isDirty true on first checkbox action itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not exactly sure why, but you can solve this issue if you explicitely retrieve the `formState`. Just add these lines after `useForm`:

```js
const {
  formState: { dirtyFields }
} = methods;
```

And then you can use either directly the `dirtyFields` variables that has been declared, or `methods.formState.dirtyFields` as you already did. Fully working example on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hidden-snowflake-37f42x?file=/src/App.tsx:774-805)

Answer (score 0):

Just as Michaël says, this is solved by destructuring formState, this is because formState is wrapped with a Proxy for improved render performance.

```
const {
  formState: { isDirty, dirtyFields }
} = useForm();
```

See react-hook-forms official documentation for formState here: [formState](https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform/formstate)

In order to have correct value for isDirty it's also important to provide defaultValues for all fields to have a single source of truth

```
  const {
    formState: { isDirty, dirtyFields },
  } = useForm({
    defaultValues: { firstName: '', lastName: '' },
  });
```